# Calculate number of days for last 6months from today in python

Tags: python, date, time, days

In python how to find the total number of days for the last 6 months ?

For example today is `7 November`(7 days in this month), and in october there are 31 days and so on until the last 6 months, and now i need to find the total for all the days in a month(until the last 6 months) like

7(Nov) + 31(Oct) + 30(Sep) +... until the last 6 months from now

Comment: Could you please elaborate and please provide an example?

Comment: I assume there's more to this than `182`?

Comment: It's a nebulous concept. If "today" is October 31, what date was six months ago? April 31 is not a valid date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with `dateutil`:

```
>>> from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
>>> import datetime
>>> delta = relativedelta(months=6)
>>> six_month_away = datetime.date.today() - delta
>>> abs((six_month_away - datetime.date.today()).days)
184
```